# openAir, 96x31 time/date data into stacked data

Tags: r, reshape

I have a table showing variable flows for each 15-minute period of the day and each day of the month, eg:

```
date,00:00,00:15,00:30,  
01-Nov,123,345,456,  
02-Nov,234,567,890
```

I want to get this into the form

```
date,value  
01-Nov 00:00,123  
01-Nov 00:15,345  
...  
02-Nov 00:00,234
```

and so on. I have tried `reshape` but I don't understand how to specify "varying" and keep getting failure messages.

Comment: Some toy data and the code you tried would be helpful

Comment: The error messages would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
require(reshape)
Df <- melt(dataframe,id.vars="date",variable_name="time")
Df <- Df[order(Df$date),]
```

where "dataframe" is the name of the data frame you're working with. If you want to combine the columns date and time, you could use eg:

```
Df2 <- with(Df,
         data.frame(
           date = paste(date,time),
           value = value
         )
       )
```

If that doesn't work or does  not give what you want, you'll have to provide us with more information.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it appears you might have only dates and data but know the associated times which you want to add. There are probably very compact methods in the zoo package that can do this in one line but here's a worked example showing a 5 or 6 step process that reads in data in 2 hour intervals (without time labels) on two days and restructures from a wide format datafrm to a long format datafrm with DateTime classed time variable:

```
require(reshape2)
txt<-"01-Nov,123,345,456,345,565,345,464,345, 123,345,456,345
02-Nov,234,567,890,345,565,345,464,345, 123,345,456,345"
 tstdf <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header=FALSE, sep=",")
mtst <- melt(tstdf, id.vars="V1",variable_name="time")
mtst$dt <- as.Date(mtst$V1, format="%d-%B")
mtst <- cbind(mtst, tm= 120*(0:11) )
mtst$dt.tm <- as.POSIXct(mtst$dt) +60*120*(0:11)
 'data.frame':  24 obs. of  6 variables:
    $ V1   : Factor w/ 2 levels " 02-Nov","01-Nov": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
    $ time : Factor w/ 12 levels "V2","V3","V4",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
    $ value: int  123 234 345 567 456 890 345 345 565 565 ...
    $ dt   :Class 'Date'  num [1:24] 14914 14915 14914 14915 14914 ...
    $ tm   : num  0 120 240 360 480 600 720 840 960 1080 ...
    $ dt.tm: POSIXct, format: "2010-10-31 20:00:00" "2010-11-01 22:00:00" ...
```

You would change the  tm= assignment to 15*(0:95) and there is a 4 hour offset on the displayed times because I am in the US Eastern tz. If you wanted to get the times to display as at midnight you could add an offset of 4 hours to the UCT default:

```
mtst$dt.tm <- as.POSIXct(mtst$dt, tz="EST") +60*120*(0:11) + 60*240
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a continuous regularly spaced series with the date in the indicated format so that there are 4 * 24 values on each line the following gives a zooreg series for it using chron for the date/time class:

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)

DF <- read.csv("myfile.csv", as.is = TRUE)
z <- zooreg(c(t(DF[-1])), start = as.chron(DF[1,1], "%d-%b"), freq = 4 * 24)
```

`as.data.frame(z)` will turn it into a data frame with the times in the row names or `data.frame(Time = time(z), Value = coredata(z))` will give time its own column (although you might be better off leaving it as a zooreg series since that will make it more convenient to further manipulate).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an xts solution:

```
library(xts)
# Sample data:
Lines <- "date,00:00,00:15,00:30
01-Nov,123,345,456
02-Nov,234,567,890"
con <- textConnection(Lines)
Data <- read.csv(con, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
close(con)
# times to add to the date for each column
mins <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]","",colnames(Data))) / 0.6 * 3600
# POSIXct index for xts object
idx <- as.POSIXct(Data$date, format="%d-%b")
# Create a list of xts object and rbind them
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(2:4, function(i) xts(Data[,i], idx+mins[i])))
```